# Python - Sorting lists of numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting, numbers

Just learning Python and got on to the subject of sorting lists. Two types of algorithms were shown: insertion and selection. So, I had an idea and created this:

```
def DiffSort(lst):
    lstDiff = [None] * len(lst)
    i = 0

    while i < len(lst):
        lstDiff[i] = lst[i] - lst[i-1] if i != 0 else lst[0]

        if lstDiff[i] < 0:
            sbj, tmp = lst[i], lstDiff[i]

            while tmp < 0:
                i -= 1
                tmp += lstDiff[i]
                lst[i+1] = lst[i]

            lst[i] = sbj
        else:
            i += 1

lst = [13,25,18,122,32,1,0.78,25,85,1,32,56,0.55,0.6,17]
print(lst)

DiffSort(lst)

print(lst)
```

Any good? Is there a similar method out there already?

Comment: [`list` has a `sort()` method.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: clever, but i think this is just insertion sort, with the downside that it won't work on arbitrary comparables (e.g. strings, tuples, etc).  so it won't outdo [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), sorry  :)

Comment: Are you looking for the best way to normally sort a list in Python, or are you interested in the theory of sorting algorithms?

Comment: He's obviously interested on sorting algorithms... and everyone keep answering as if he just asked how to sort a list xD Anyway, OnT: the `lstDiff` list seems superfluous, you are only using the current index (which could be replaced by a simple variable). Also, agree with Eevee and that it seems like insertion sort using diff instead of conditionals.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback, working my way through an introduction to Python. Just seeing if I was on to something there... lol.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort()` if you want to sort a list in-place.

`sorted(list)` if you want to return a sorted copy of the list.

The second option works with any iterable type, whereas the first is list-exclusive (although some other types may have the same or a similar function defined as well, but you can generally not expect that).

Since you seem to care about the algorithmic part of it, this may be of interest to you:
http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt

Comment: Cheers, looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't lst.sort() good enough?  It's bound to be much faster than a Python solution that has to run in O(n^2) time.